# Storing dates with prefix in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I need to store and sort dates with prefixes (100 bc or 1940), normally it will be two fields of datetime type. How it should looks like in this case?

Comment: What are the two fields? What does the table look like? more info please..?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to store two types of information in one column. May I remind you of first normal form?

Provide more information on what you want to do or we won't be able to help you.